# How to implement select all on xamnumericeditor when event editmode started is triggered?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

We can can do this in xaml.cs but How to apply this in xaml itself?
Any ideas?

```
 private void XamNumericEditor_EditModeStarted(object sender,Infragistics.Windows.Editors.Events.EditModeStartedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((XamNumericEditor)sender).SelectAll();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can write C# code into XAML file:

```
<x:Code>
    <![CDATA[            
    private void XamNumericEditor_EditModeStarted(object sender,Infragistics.Windows.Editors.Events.EditModeStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((XamNumericEditor)sender).SelectAll();
    }
]]>
</x:Code>
```

Comment: No, I want something like this for example                                                           
<Style x:Key="XamNumericEditorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="EditModeStarted" >
                        <!--TODO-->
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>                                                                                          So that when Edit mode is triggered Xamnumericeditor content should be selected all